# How to debug none working search query?

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm developing an website that I didn't built the foundation for.
When I try to implement a simple search query I just get nothing in response. There is no errors showing up in normal php error reporting. The only thing showing is complete blank result. If I turn on debug.log I don't get any returns from WP.

This is the code i'm running:

```
$args = array(
's' => 'test',
'post_type' => 'posts'
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
//inside the loop
the_title();
the_content();
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If I run it without the 's' => 'test', parameter I get results returned. I tried different post types, different search queries etc... Everything works as soon as I remove the s parameter.

I run the query on a custom post type single page.

What could be the problem? And how do I debug it? Can't find any clue to what is wrong.

Comment: "I run the query on a custom post type single page." - in your example you run it on `posts`, can you post the actual `$args`? Does your CPT even have searchable fields (I believe title and content) filled?

Comment: Kero’s point about searchable fields is important. If your custom post type’s content is all stored in custom fields then they won’t be returned in search.

Comment: The first thing for debugging is to disable all plugins and switch to a default theme. Second, check `exclude_from_search` parameter where you register the custom post type (and other parameters as well).

Comment: This is the query i'm running, what I meant by "I Run the query on a custom post type single page" is that I am running this exact query on a template page for a custom post type. So the query doesn't even work for normal post types... I will try look into your suggestions about disable plugins and looking for exclude_from_search. Thanks!